# Captured pic not able to preview in Imageview for kitkat.?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-imageview, android-camera-intent

I am trying to capture the picture and show it in `Imageview` as a preview, it is displaying when I do extends `Activity` but in `Fragment` the image is not displaying as preview.But the same piece of code working in Lollipop onwards, not working in kitkat. 
Below is my code snippet.

```
   public class MarkAttendance extends Fragment {


        private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
        public static int count = 0;
        Uri outputFileUri; String file;
        ImageView imageView;

        int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 100;
        public MarkAttendance() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        TextView textView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mark_attendance, container, false);


            final Fragment frag = this;
            imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            Button capture =  v.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
           // Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
            capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);

                    }
            });


            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            Log.d("resulvalues","******    "+requestCode+ " "+resultCode+ " "+data);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"******    "+requestCode+ " "+resultCode+ " "+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");

                Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(mphoto);
            }

        }

    }
```

and my manifest file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.msupply.com.ideatattendance">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="standard" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.LoginActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.HomeActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.RegisterationActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.TakePhotoCamera">


        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please debug onActivityResult method in debug mode also remove super.onActivityResult from fragment.

Comment: can you share what you are getting for **data.getExtras().get("data");**??

Comment: @SubhechhuKhanal  code is not executing the `If` condition only which is in `onActivityResult`

Comment: Follow the documentation as given in the answer. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Take photo camera in following way as on developer.android.com:

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

You have to create a file and give it to camera intent, then camera would save image on the file you have given.